# Read byte array from string and create images

Tags: java, javafx

I have an image file which I must pass as a `String` field in JSON. I will convert the image file

`byte [] array = Files.readAllBytes (Paths.get (file.getPath ()));`

and write this byte array to a file with `new String (array)`

After I get it again and parse this JSON file, I get a string that contains my byte array. How now from this line to get my array byte and create exactly the same image as it was in the original?

Comment: `new String (array)` is not a good idea because `array` is not the encoding of a string. Instead, use a proper encoding for transmitting binary data over JSON, like Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since java 8 this task it's pretty straightforward using `Base64 Encoder`

```
String imageAsString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);
```

And decode to byte array again:

```
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageAsString);
```